# best way of solving a system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is what is the most straight forward of solving a system equations such as these. I usually end up isolating a variable and substituting but then there are so many steps I tend to make mistakes.

How would you approach this problem?
$$x-2\lambda x^3=0$$
$$y-2\lambda y^3=0$$
$$x^4+y^4=16$$

Comment: Is this a lagrangian optimisation ;)? If so you know $x=0$ and $y=0$ are (separately) possible solutions, you can plug these into the constraint to get one solution set, then you can eliminate $\lambda$ in the top 2 and plug into the last one possibly to get another set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) If $x=0$ then $y = \pm 2$ so $$\lambda ={1\over 2y^2} = {1\over 8}$$

2.) If $x\ne 0$ then $x^2 ={1\over 2\lambda}$

$...$ a) If $y\ne 0$ then $y^2={1\over 2\lambda}$ so $$2{1\over 4\lambda ^2} =16\implies \lambda = \pm{1\over 4\sqrt{2}} \implies x=y=...$$

$...$  b) If $y=0$ then $x  = \pm 2$ so $$\lambda ={1\over 2y^2} = {1\over 8}$$

Comment: Thank you ojd!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write your system in thew form

$$x(1-2\lambda x^2)=0$$
$$y(1-2\lambda y^2)=0$$
From here we get $x=0$ or $y=0$ or

$$x^2=\frac{1}{2\lambda}$$ or $$y^2=\frac{1}{2\lambda}$$ so we get

$$\frac{1}{4\lambda^2}+\frac{1}{4\lambda^2}=16$$  and you will get $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

$xy\ne0$ because if not we would have $0=1$(Why?).
Then $x^2=y^2=\dfrac{1}{2\lambda}$ from which we have 
$$(x,y,\lambda)=\left(2\sqrt2,\space2\sqrt2,\space\dfrac{\sqrt2}{8}\right)$$